# Facebook Graph API: Unable to find the created A/B Test in console

Tags: javascript, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, ads

I am trying to create A/B test using facebook graph API. The documentation I follow:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/split-testing

The documentation mentions following curl command:

```
curl \
-F 'name="new study"' \
-F 'description="test creative"' \ 
-F 'start_time=1478387569' \
-F 'end_time=1479597169' \
-F 'type=SPLIT_TEST' \
-F 'cells=[{name:"Group A",treatment_percentage:50,adsets:[<AD_SET_ID>]},{name:"Group B",treatment_percentage:50,adsets:[<AD_SET_ID>]}]' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \ https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/ad_studies
```

I am able to run this command successfully and get the split test ID which has been created, but I am unable to find the created split test at:

https://web.facebook.com/test-and-learn/ -> Tests

The created test is fetch-able through API GET endpoint, but it does not exist on facebook console. Here is the place where I am trying to find it:

[image: Facebook Experiment]

My goal is to create facebook ads A/B test through graph API. Is there any other documentation for this? or am I understanding something wrong there?